# Merge two lists in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have following two lists in makefile:

```
SERVERS=172.16.0.117 172.16.0.147
PORTS=1600 1601
```

I want the new list as following

```
172.16.0.117-1600 172.16.0.17-1601 172.16.0.147-1600 172.16.0.147-1601
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong. Could you please help me out? Please have a look at makefile source code and the output. Thanks in advance.

Makefile source code:

```
SERVERS=172.16.0.117 172.16.0.147
PORTS=1600 1601

SERVER=$(addprefix Connect-to-, $(SERVERS))
PORT=$(addprefix $(SERVER)-, $(PORTS))

testall:
        echo "PORTS - $(PORT)"

Output of makefile:
#make
echo "PORTS - Connect-to-172.16.0.117 Connect-to-172.16.0.147-1600 Connect-to-172.16.0.117 Connect-to-172.16.0.147-1601"
PORTS - Connect-to-172.16.0.117 Connect-to-172.16.0.147-1600 Connect-to-172.16.0.117 Connect-to-172.16.0.147-1601
```

Comment: `addprefix` takes a single prefix not a list of prefixes. So that is taking the entirety of the value of `$(SERVER)` and prepending it to every word in `$(PORTS)`.

Comment: Just to be extra clear your output there is `PORTS - "Connect-to-172.16.0.117 Connect-to-172.16.0.147-1600" "Connect-to-172.16.0.117 Connect-to-172.16.0.147-1601"`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
PORT := $(foreach p,$(PORTS),$(patsubst %,%-$p,$(SERVERS)))
```